# Error Mocking Firebase Admin in Jest: "TypeError: admin.firestore is not a function"

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a function to handle connecting to Cloud Firestore through the Admin SDK. I know the function works fine, as the app connects and allows writing to the database.

Now I am trying to test this function with Jest. To avoid testing outside the scope of this function, I am mocking the firebase-admin Node module. However, my test is failing with the error "TypeError: admin.firestore is not a function".

My function and tests are both written in TypeScript, run via ts-jest, but I don't think this is a TypeScript error, as VS Code has no complaints. I believe this is an issue with Jest's automatic mocking.

`admin.firebase()` is a valid call. The TypeScript definition file defines it as `function firestore(app?: admin.app.App): admin.firestore.Firestore;`

I've read over the Jest docs, but I'm not understanding how to fix this.

This is my function:

```
// /src/lib/database.ts

import * as admin from "firebase-admin"

/**
 * Connect to the database
 * @param key - a base64 encoded JSON string of serviceAccountKey.json
 * @returns - a Cloud Firestore database connection
 */
export function connectToDatabase(key: string): FirebaseFirestore.Firestore {
  // irrelevant code to convert the key

  try {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(key),
    })
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Firebase initialization failed. ${error.message}`)
  }

  return admin.firestore() // this is where it throws the error
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
// /tests/lib/database.spec.ts

jest.mock("firebase-admin")
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import { connectToDatabase } from "@/lib/database"

describe("database connector", () => {
  it("should connect to Firebase when given valid credentials", () => {
    const key = "ewogICJkdW1teSI6ICJUaGlzIGlzIGp1c3QgYSBkdW1teSBKU09OIG9iamVjdCIKfQo=" // dummy key

    connectToDatabase(key) // test fails here

    expect(admin.initializeApp).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(admin.credential.cert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(admin.firestore()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Here are my relevant (or possibly relevant) package.json (installed with Yarn v1):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "expect-more-jest": "^4.0.2",
    "jest": "^25.5.4",
    "jest-chain": "^1.1.5",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.5",
    "jest-junit": "^10.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^25.5.0"
  }
}
```

And my jest config:

```js
// /jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest-extended", "expect-more-jest", "jest-chain"],
  preset: "ts-jest",
  errorOnDeprecated: true,
  testEnvironment: "node",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "json"],
  testMatch: ["<rootDir>/tests/**/*.(test|spec).(ts|js)"],
  clearMocks: true,
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code looks good. [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) mocks all the methods of the library and, by default, all of them will return `undefined` when called.

## Explanation

The problem you are seeing is related to how the `firebase-admin` module methods are being defined.

In the source code for `firebase-admin` package, the `initializeApp` method is being defined as a method in the `FirebaseNamespace.prototype`:

```
FirebaseNamespace.prototype.initializeApp = function (options, appName) {
    return this.INTERNAL.initializeApp(options, appName);
};
```

However, the `firestore` method is being defined as a property:

```
Object.defineProperty(FirebaseNamespace.prototype, "firestore", {
    get: function () {
        [...]
        return fn;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

It seems that `jest.mock` is able to mock the methods declared directly in the `prototype` (that's the reason why your call to `admin.initializeApp` does not throw an error) but not the ones defined as properties.

## Solution

To overcome this problem you can add a mock for the `firestore` property before running your test:

```
// /tests/lib/database.spec.ts
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import { connectToDatabase } from "@/lib/database"

jest.mock("firebase-admin")

describe("database connector", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Complete firebase-admin mocks
    admin.firestore = jest.fn()
  })

  it("should connect to Firebase when given valid credentials", () => {
    const key = "ewogICJkdW1teSI6ICJUaGlzIGlzIGp1c3QgYSBkdW1teSBKU09OIG9iamVjdCIKfQo=" // dummy key

    connectToDatabase(key) // test fails here

    expect(admin.initializeApp).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(admin.credential.cert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(admin.firestore).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

## Alternative solution

Since the previous solution did not work for you, I'll suggest an alternative solution. Instead of assigning the value of the `firestore` method you can define the property so that it returns a mocked function.

To simplify the mock, I would create a little helper `mockFirestoreProperty` in your test file:

```
// /tests/lib/database.spec.ts
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import { connectToDatabase } from "@/lib/database"

jest.mock("firebase-admin")

describe("database connector", () => {
  // This is the helper. It creates a mock function and returns it
  // when the firestore property is accessed.
  const mockFirestoreProperty = admin => {
    const firestore = jest.fn();
    Object.defineProperty(admin, 'firestore', {
      get: jest.fn(() => firestore),
      configurable: true
    });
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Complete firebase-admin mocks
    mockFirestoreProperty(admin);
  })

  it("should connect to Firebase when given valid credentials", () => {
    const key = "ewogICJkdW1teSI6ICJUaGlzIGlzIGp1c3QgYSBkdW1teSBKU09OIG9iamVjdCIKfQo=" // dummy key

    connectToDatabase(key) // test fails here

    expect(admin.initializeApp).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(admin.credential.cert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(admin.firestore).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but TypeScript complains about ```admin.firestore = jest.fn()``` "Cannot assign to 'firestore' because it is a read-only property." The Jest plugin for ESLint then auto-fixes it to ```jest.spyOn(admin, "firestore").mockImplementation()```, but then my test fails with "Error: Cannot spy the firestore property because it is not a function; undefined given instead". Trying to spy on "firestore()" gives me a TS error "No overload matches this call."

Comment: Ok, things are getting trickier. Can you try if `jest.spyOn(admin, 'firestore', 'get').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn())` works for you?

Comment: TS throws an error for "firestore": "No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(object: typeof import("c:/Development/CephalonTobran/CephalonTobranBackend/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.d.ts"), method: "SDK_VERSION" | "apps" | "credential", accessType: "get"): SpyInstance<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"firestore"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"SDK_VERSION" | "apps" | "credential"'. "  It goes on, but I don't have enough space for the full error.

Comment: Hi @EdRands, I have added an alternative solution. Hope it helps!

Comment: That's the ticket! Woot! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It works properly to combine your own mocks with its auto-mocks when you initially mock it, i.e.:

```js
jest.mock('firebase-admin', () => ({
  ...jest.mock('firebase-admin'),
  credential: {
    cert: jest.fn(),
  },
  initializeApp: jest.fn(),
  firestore: jest.fn(),
}));
```